# Run switchmap operator when calling next - Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, observable, angular7

I use subject and **async** pipe to make http request and search based on search term. I used the angular tutorial for doing this that uses the **switchmap** operator and some delay time for **keyup** method.

It is working fine for key strokes, but for the first time i want to make the request call and show the list then user can search if she wants.

But with calling **next** the **switchmap** operator is not triggering!

Search input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search name" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keyup)="callSearch()">
```

typescript code:

```
 products$: Observable<ProdSearch[]>;
 searchProducts$ = new Subject<string>();
 callSearch() {
   if (this.searchTerm.length > 0 ){
    this.searchProducts$.next(this.searchTerm);
   }
 }
```

Subscription:

```
this.products$ = this.searchProducts$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(term => {
    const options: PagingOptions = {};
    options.limit = "5";
    if (term.length !== 0) {
      options.filterOptions = "name_search_" + this.searchTerm;
    }

    return this.service.getCollection<ProdSearch>(this.baseUrl + 'products/search', options)
      .pipe(map(collection => collection.records))
  })
```

I want to do run the **switchmap** for the first time with a button but it won't work and it only works with the key strokes.

```
showLastProducts() {
this.showChangeList = true;
this.searchProducts$.next(''); // The switchmap won't work
}
```

Comment: Try using a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject`, or use the `startWith` operator. The issue is that subjects don't emit a first value, so you have to either do it manually, or use their little brother, the behavior one.

Comment: ... or add `startWith` operator

Answer (score 0):

Try switching:

```
searchProducts$ = new Subject<string>();
```

To this:

```
searchProducts$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

This will emit a value before you type anything.